# Let $n \geq 3$ be an integer. Let $ X \in M_2 (\mathbb R)$ be such that $X^n+X^{n-2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

a) Prove that $\det X=0$. Hint: Show that $\det (X^2+I_2)\ne0$.

My answer

$X^n+X^{n-2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
X^{n-2}(X^2+Id)=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $\det(X^{n-2}) \neq 0$, then apply the inverse on both sides.

$(X^{n-2})^{-1} X^{n-2}(X^2+Id)=(X^{n-2})^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
(X^2+Id)=(X^{n-2})^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow$
$\det(X^2+Id)=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \det(X^{n-2})^{-1} \rightarrow \det(X^2+Id)=0$.

Now, suppose $\det(X^{n-2}) = 0$, then $\det(X)\cdot\det(X)\dotsm\det(X)=0$, so $\det(X)=0$.

I'm pretty confident about the second half, but the first part is incorrect, given I proved that $\det(X^2+Id)=0$, not that $\det(X)=0$.

Source: Titu Andreescu - Essential Linear
Algebra with Applications: A Problem-Solving Approach 2.2.1 ex.8

Comment: Umm, did you check your MathJax?

Comment: In particular `X^n^-^2` is not valid.

Comment: First thing: What is $R$? Surely a unital ring. But is it a domain?

Comment: Second thing: Titu Andresscu wrote *many* books. Which are you referring to?

Comment: Hello, guys. I just started learning linear algebra. I just wrote what was in the book. Sorry for now knowing what this and that mean.

Comment: Just started. So what do you know about? You obviously know facts about determinants. Do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors? And is $R$ really $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hello, page 1 says "the field R of real numbers". So yes, R stands for Real. As for me, I know the basic aspects of linear algebra, mainly about matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\det(X^2+I)=0.$ Then one of the eigenvalues of $X^2$ must be $-1,$ which in turn means that one of the eigenvalues of $X$ must be either $i$ or $-i.$ As $X$ is meant to be a *real* matrix, its complex eigenvalues must be pairs of complex conjugates. Therefore, the eigenvalues of $X$ are $i$ and $-i.$ Then its characteristic polynomial is $\chi(t)=t^2+1$ which means (Cayley-Hamilton) that $X^2+I=0.$ But then $X^{n}+X^{n-2}=0,$ too, which contradicts $X^{n}+X^{n-2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 \\ -1 && 1 \end{bmatrix}.$ Therefore $\det(X^2+I)\neq 0.$

Take the determinant on both sides of $X^{n}+X^{n-2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 \\ -1 && 1 \end{bmatrix}.$ You get
$$
\det\left(X^{n-2}\right)\det\left(X^2+I\right) = 0
$$
The second factor cannot be $0.$ Therefore, the first factor is $0$, which in turn means that $\det(X)=0.$

Comment: Hello, could you explain to me why the one of the eigenvalues of $X^2$ is −1, and why X has as eigenvalue $i$ or $-i$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, another thing, which rule did you use to prove that $Det (X^n + X^{n-2})=Det(X^{n-2})Det(X^2+I)$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are the numbers $\lambda$ that fulfill $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. We have $\det(X^2+I) = \det((X^2) - (-1)\cdot I) = 0.$ With $A=X^2$ and $\lambda = -1$ you can see that $-1$ must be an eigenvalue of $X^2$.

Comment: The determinant of a product of matrices is the product of the determinants of the matrices, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups)

Comment: This also explains why one of $i$ or $-i$ must be an eigenvalue of $X.$ We have $\det(X^2+I) = \det((X+iI)(X-iI)) = \det(X+iI)\det(X-iI).$ One of the factors must be $0$.

Comment: It is also possible to get the result without eigenvalues and without complex numbers. Let me know if you are interested in that approach, I will post another answer, then. Hint: It uses that $t^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[t]$ and hence can have a common divisor with the characteristic polynomial of a $2\times 2$ matrix only if it is the characteristic polynomial itself (or a scalar multiple of it.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm extremely grateful for your answer! It's not necessary to give another answer, I already understood what should be done.