# Let $n \geq 3$ be an integer. Let $X \in M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ be such that $X^n+X^{n-2}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Tags: linear-algebra

**c)Find all possible matrices X satisfying the original equation.**

What I tired to do was use an induction argument (for n=3, n=k and n=k+1), but someone already told me this doesn't prove anything. Now I'm out of ideias.

Comment: It seems that$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ satisfies the desired equality.

Comment: No idea if there's a pretty solution, but some preliminary thoughts: The fact that your matrices are $2\times 2$ means that they're either 0 (which obviously doesn't work), or invertible, or rank $1$. I think that powers of rank $1$ matrices are computable in the $2\times 2$ case which gives an easier system of equations in the matrix entries (not sure if it's easy enough to solve). If $X$ is invertible then this implies that $X^2+I$ is not invertible, which gives a probably-harder system of equations, but still only quadratic so there might still be some hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is largely based on a solution to a related problem [[1]](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1849276p12466356):

1. Under the hypotheses of the problem, one can prove that $\det(X)=0$ [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4762184/let-n-geq-3-be-an-integer-let-x-in-m-2-mathbb-r-be-such-that-xnx?rq=1), hence one of the eigenvalues of $X$ is $0$; let $\lambda$ be its other eigenvalue.
2. In general, if $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ matrix $M$, then $\text{tr}(M^k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  In our case, $X$ has only two eigenvalues, and since one of them is $0$, we have $\text{tr}(X^k)=\lambda^k.$
3. Therefore, taking the trace of both sides of
   $$
   X^n+X^{n-2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}
   $$
   we obtain the relation $\lambda^n+\lambda^{n-2}=2.$
4. If $n\geq 3$ is odd, $\lambda=1$ is a solution to the equation $\lambda^n+\lambda^{n-2}=2$. It is the only real solution, as the function $f(\lambda)=\lambda^n+\lambda^{n-2}$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}$. If $n$ is even, there are only two real solutions, $\lambda=\pm 1$, as $f(\lambda)$ is decreasing in the interval $(-\infty,0)$ and increasing in the interval $(0,\infty)$.
5. The characteristic polynomial of the two-dimensional matrix $X$ is $p(x)=x^2-\text{tr}(X)x+\det(X)=x^2-\lambda x$. It follows from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) that $p(X)=0$, i.e., $X^2=\lambda X$.
6. Therefore, if $n$ is odd, $X^2=X$ and the relation $(1)$ reduces to
   $$
   2X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \implies
   X=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & 1/2 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \tag{2}
   $$
   which is the solution found by @Math1000. On the other hand, there are two possibilities if $n$ is even: if $\lambda=1$, then $X$ is also given by $(2)$, but if $\lambda=-1$, then $X^2=-X$ and the relation $(1)$ reduces to
   $$
   -2X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \implies
   X=\begin{bmatrix} -1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -1/2 \\ \end{bmatrix}. \tag{3}
   $$
7. In conclusion: $(2)$ is a solution to $(1)$ for all integers $n\geq 3$, and $(3)$ is also a solution if $n\geq 3$ is even. Besides, these are the only possible solutions.

---

[1] See Filipjack's answer in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1849276p12466356.

[2] See Reinhard Meier's answer in [Let $n \geq 3$ be an integer. Let $ X \in M_2 (\mathbb R)$ be such that $X^n+X^{n-2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4762184/let-n-geq-3-be-an-integer-let-x-in-m-2-mathbb-r-be-such-that-xnx?rq=1).

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem